# Sum and product macros in LISP

Tags: macros, sum, lisp, tail-recursion

I need to write a program, which evaluates sum in some range of variable for some body like:

`(sum-range (i 2 N) (sin i))`

Generally:

`(sum-range (iteration-variable begin end) my-body`

for this:

[image]

And the same for product. I can't use any loop/iterative construction, only write one for myself, *using tail recursion*.

I need it to be done with macros, but can't get an idea of these things. I don't ask for the completed code, just need some explanation on macros and usage. First, how do variables (`iteration-variable`) being passed to `sin`? How can I implement tail recursion inside macros?

As far as I understand macros creates some list, which is substituted to the point of calling and evaluated there. Am I right? So my solution is to create list of `sin i` for each i between 2 and N and then `apply`+` to this list. Is it ok?

Comment: So for (i 1 1000) you would create 1000 sin calls in a list? Does that make sense?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you should look what you want to write, then, what code it should expand to.

A macro takes the input *forms* (the code) as an argument and transforms it.  So, the argument list needs to have the structure of what you want to write.

In your case, you want to write

```
(sum-range (iteration-variable begin end) #|my-body|#)
```

where `my-body` are some forms that calculate something with the variable.  You could specify this as a single form, but sometimes it is convenient to have arbitrary calculations in such a body, so I'll allow the general case below.

Your argument list then needs to reflect that (I use `var` instead of `iteration-variable`):

```
(defmacro sum-range ((var begin end) &body body)
  #|how to sum body with var...|#)
```

Now, what would you need to write without the macro?  You loop over the range summing the evaluation of body with var.  Fortunately for this explanation, this translates quite well to a `loop` construct.

```
(loop :for var :from begin :to end
      :sum #|what to sum with var...|#)
```

So the macro needs to produce such a form.  We have the very nice code template syntax (quasiquote) that lets us express this nicely:

```
(defmacro sum-range ((var begin end) &body body)
  `(loop :for ,var :from ,begin :to ,end
         :sum (progn ,@body)))
```

(The `progn` allows multiple forms in the body, returning the value of the last form.)

This is about the same as writing

```
(defmacro sum-range ((var begin end) &body body)
  (list 'loop :for var :from begin :to end
        :sum (list* 'progn body)))
```

Now, when you write

```
(sum-range (i 2 n)
  (sin i))
```

it will macro-expand to

```
(loop :for i :from 2 :to n
      :sum (progn
             (sin i)))
```

Your mission is now to replace the `loop` solution with a tail-recursive function.  You should first define the recursion function and then use the macro to transform the code to an invocation of that function.  Passing the body to that function might be done by wrapping it in a `lambda` (an anonymous function).

Comment: Can I define loop func inside (with `labels` or `let`)?

Comment: Yes, of course, but that will mean that the macro expands to that creation at every place you use it.  I find it clearer to put it outside.